# ABAP Report Logic

Tags: abap

I am new to ABAP.

I have a requirement in abap.In my presentation server ,there is header text file, which I want to upload data from that text file to Header table. But the custom table is having different structure from text file.

It includes extra 4 fields- **PO_CREATED_DATE, PO_CREATED_BY, PO_CHANGED_DATE, PO_CHANGED_BY**.
These fields have to populate from our report program using sy-datum and sy-uname.

In this scenario,we have to check,If the data is existing then populate
**PO_CHANGED_DATE, PO_CHANGED_BY**    and if the data is not there,then populate **PO_CREATED_DATE, PO_CREATED_BY**.

Please let me know the logic...

Comment: Please provide the code you already have and ask specific question. This is not a free code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

first load the file into an internal table with only 1 very long field (long enough to contain at least the longest possible line in the file). Then loop over that itab and split the individual lines using the separator that is used in the file. You split the contents into a work area that contains all your fields, including the 4 extra fields that may or may not be included in the file. Make sure to clear the work area before splitting the line into the WA. Append the work area to an itab with the same structure as the wa, then continue with the next line.

After that, loop over that second itab and check for lines where your 4 extra fields are initial. Those are the lines where you need to add the data by code. After that, do whatever you need to do with the data in the itab.

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded text file header data to it_input1 using gui_upload.But the **it_input1** is not having extra 4 fields.I declared another itable **it_header** which is having the same structure as **Header** custom table.Now i wnt to check whether the data in the it_input 1 is alredy existing or not.If existing ,populate **it_header-po_changed_date** and **it_header-po_changed_by** or else, **it_header-po_created_date** and **it_header-po_created_by.**

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the "Pattern" Button on top. Select ABAP Objects an press enter.
Now you can supply the class and methdo you want to call.

**CL_GUI_FRONTEND_SERVICES=>GUI_UPLOAD**

**GUI_UPLOAD** is a static method. If you are new that is the easiest way to see which parameters must be supplied. With the forward navigation (double-click) you can check the signature for typing the parameter variables.
Then you just need to convert your data (e.g. **SPLIT**). I can only recommend to use the F1-Help.

Kind regards!